# Python Requests and Github Cron Job

Tags: python, python-requests, cron, github-actions

**I am beginner in python and github cron jobs**

I have written a python code, in which I am calling some api url using requests.

My question is, when I am running my python code on local system, it is producing corrct output.
But when I am scheduling a cron job in github, it runs for 10 secs and then the job is completed, but it is not producing expected output.

Usually when I run python code on local system, it takes 30secs - 1 min(because I am calling requests in a loop).

But cron job gets completed in 10 secs, and it is skipping this particular loop.

Please help me in this problem.

Github cron code

```
# This is a basic workflow to help you get started with Actions

name: M3U generator

# Controls when the action will run. 
on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '0 0/3 * * *'
    
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
  
  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build"
  build:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      # Runs a single command using the runners shell
      #- name: Run a one-line script
      #  run: echo testing!

      # Runs a set of commands using the runners shell 
      - name: config
        run: |
          git config --global user.email "XXXX@gmail.com"
          git config --global user.name "XXXX"
      
      
      - name: Main
        run: |
           python3 ./scripts/test.py
         
        
      - name: git add
        run: |
          git add -A
          ls -la 
          
      - name: commit & push
        run: |
          git commit -m " updated"
          git push
```

python file code

```py
import requests
headers = {
    'sec-ch-ua': '^\\^Chromium^\\^;v=^\\^92^\\^, ^\\^',
    'Referer': 'https://www.a.com/',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36',
}

genres = ['Hindi%20News',
          'Hindi%20Entertainment',
          'Music',
          'Entertainment',
          'Movie',
          'Movies',
          'Lifestyle',
          ]

params = {
    'sort_by_field': 'channel_number',
    'sort_order': 'ASC',
    'genres': '',
    'country': 'IN',
    'translation': 'en',
    'languages': 'hi',
}

channels = []


for genre in genres:
    print('In genre')
    params['genres'] = genre
    a_channel_list = response = requests.get('https://xxxxxxx/v1/channel/bygenre', headers=headers, params=params).json()
    for a_channel in a_channel_list['items'][0]['items']:
        id = a_channel['id']

        #api url needs to be checked once finalised
        api_url = "https://yyyyyy/?url={}".format(id)
        json = requests.get(api_url).text
        #hls = json['stream_url_hls']

        #adding a channels
        if a_channel['genres'][0]['value'] == 'Hindi News':
            a_cat = 'News'
        elif a_channel['genres'][0]['value'] == 'Hindi Entertainment':
            a_cat = 'Entertainment'
        else:
            a_cat = a_channel['genres'][0]['value']
        channel = {
            'title': a_channel['title'],
            'category': a_cat,
            'language': a_channel['languages'][0],
            'url': json}
        channels.append(channel)
```

Comment: at the very least, it is missing dependencies and github auth

Comment: What is the content of test.py?

Comment: shared the content of python file

Comment: @Marat could you explain what dependencies and auth is missing?
Please note, only the portion of code mentioned here in python is not working, rest of the code is working fine in cron job.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @ramansingh did it help?

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu instance running actions comes clean, without any Python packages installed. In fact, there is no guarantee it will have any specific version of Python installed. So, the first step is to install Python and script dependencies:

```
# optional, but will help with stability by fixing Python version
- name: Set up Python
  uses: actions/setup-python@v2
  with:
    python-version: '3.8'

# this is what causes the error - add before `Main`
- name: dependencies
  run: |
    python3 -m pip install requests
```

I might be wrong about the second part. The concern is:

Github actions have a github token in their context, which is used for git auth. AFAIK, the token is generated for the user triggering the workflow, thus I assumed cronjob runs don't have a token associated - but I might be wrong here. If you see an auth error in `commit & push`, you'll need to explicitly set `GITHUB_TOKEN` secret.